# personal letters with koma-script

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, letters

KOMA-Script provides  the `scrlttr2` and `scrletter` classes, which, in contrast to the standard class `letter`,
has the flexible design common to other KOMA-Script classes.

One observation about `letter` is the very good results, with no configuration,  for personal letters, for example, letters with just a date, salutation, body, and signature.

The design of KOMA-Script letter classes appears to emphasize   templates called *Letter Class Options*, of which several are included in the distribution, representing formatting standards for business correspondence in various countries. Among these, `DIN`,
representing a definition given by the [German Institute for the Standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Institut_f%C3%BCr_Normung), appears to be loaded by default if none is given explicitly. Such design seems to exclude the possibility of creating a letter with formatting not related to some business standard, except of course through  creating an LCO representing some preferred formatting for a personal letter.

For example,
the KOMA-Script manual (Table 4.19) describes the DIN Letter Class Option set as follows:

> parameters for letters on A4 paper, complying with German standard DIN 676;suitable for window envelopes in the sizes C4, C5, C6, and C6/5 (C6 long).

Naturally, windowed envelopes are not generally useful for personal letters, nor is it useful that such a requirement would constrain the formatting of the letter.

An obvious suggestion is not to use KOMA-Script for personal letters, in preference to the standard class, but I have come to value the comparatively flexible design of KOMA-Script classes over the standard ones.

What might be a good way to invoke either `scrlttr2` or `scrletter` without including any formatting details specifically targeted for commercial correspondence?

A minimal example of a personal letter might be one that includes a date, a salutation, a body, and a closing, but not necessarily any address information.

Comment: Maybe you can show, what you've got so far. It's hard to guess, what you want...

Comment: @DG, A letter with the KOMA-Script classes is by default formatted as a German business letter. What I want, if nothing else, is not that. I also don't want a letter formatted as  Swiss, American, or any other business letter. What I have so far is one of these.

Comment: What I meant was: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing, what you've got so far

Comment: @DG I don't think that a MWE applies to this question. I am asking about design not troubleshooting. At least, I have no idea how a MWE would look for this question.

Comment: Well, without code to play with and more detailed descriptions of what you think, a personal letter consists of, it will be hard to help

Comment: @DG Well in that sense I gave a minimal example by describing a letter with a date, salutation, body, and signature (no addresses, subject, etc.). I think code would add rather little since most know what those are already.

Comment: The manual (Table 4.19) describes the DIN Class Options set as follows: *parameters for letters on A4 paper, complying with German standard DIN 676;suitable for window envelopes in the sizes C4, C5, C6, and C6/5 (C6 long).* It is not desired that the format used in a personal letter is a format intended to accommodate a windowed envelope. I can show you code that generates a letter that fits in a windowed envelope, and say, "this is what I have but not what I want." I'm not sure doing so is helpful.

Comment: @DG I'm just looking for a suggestion to point me in the right direction. I don't have an expectation that someone would give me a recipe. The question is in the category of understanding the KOMA-Script design, not "please do my homework for me".

Answer (score 3):

You can disable `foldmarks`, `addrfield` and `firsthead` using `foldmarks=false,addrfield=false,firsthead=false` as class options (with class `scrlttr2`) or package options (with package `scrletter`) or using `\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=false,addrfield=false,firsthead=false}`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=false,addrfield=false,firsthead=false}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Hello,}
\blindtext
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To remove the vertical space reserved for the addresse field add:

```
\addtoplength[-]{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrheight}}
```

If you set the variable `fromname` and do not want that `\closing` adds the value of `fromname` then clear the variable `signature`:

```latex
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{signature}{}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=false,addrfield=false,firsthead=false}
\addtoplength[-]{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrheight}}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{signature}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Hello,}
\blindtext
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, that most of the predefined `lco` files expecte paper size `a4`, eg. the preloaded `DIN.lco`. If you use another paper sizes, you will get a warning. If you do not need a special position of a letter element (like the position of the address field for windowed envelopes) you can ignore this warning. For `paper=letter` you can also load letter option `UScommercial9` or `UScommercial9DW`. If you use another paper size, eg. `paper=a5`, and need special positions of a letter elements, then you have to define an own `lco` file.

Comment: I suppose a further point is that the `UScommercial9` LCO may be desired, in preference to the default `DIN`, if the paper size is US *Letter*.

Comment: If you do not need a special position of letter elements (like the address field for windowed envelopes) then you can ignore the warning regarding the paper size.

Comment: The design of the default LCO assumes *A4*, so I would  think it wiser to use one designed for *Letter* in case of that paper size.

Comment: I thought you did not want the address field, header, footer etc.? The main differences between the `lco`s are the positions of the addresse field and the fold marks. Additionally I have added a short remark regarding the paper size.